# Stop table row toggle upon clicking link

Tags: javascript, jquery, togglebutton

What I am trying to do is to stop the toggling when someone clicks on a url link in the table row.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#report tr:odd").addClass("odd");
    $("#report tr:not(.odd)").hide();
    $("#report tr:first-child").show();

    $("#report tr.odd").click(function () {
        $(this).next("tr").toggle();
        $(this).find(".arrow").toggleClass("up");
    });
    //$("#report").jExpand();
});
```

The url link sits right on the same toggling row which in turn when someone clicks the url link, it also toggles the row which I am trying to stop. Any pointers on how to do this?

Comment: could you post the html

Comment: please post html of what is getting toggled, what you want to get toggled and what you don't want to get toggled, code alone doesn't make sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the anchor is in tr element,whenever click on `anchor` is called ,the event will be propagated to the parent `tr`  and its click function is also executed.

```
$('a').click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

this stops the event of anchor click to bubble up to the parent

Answer (score 2):

I think below might work for you. Not tested though.

add a Javascript function call in your link

```
$("#ANCHIOR_ID").click(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
    // then do your job there that you want to do in on click
  });
```