# PHP Click link instead of Row Toggle

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am creating a table using tablesorter. The table has a google chart hidden on row click. Some of the contents in the table has a link to a separate page. When I click on the link, it acts as the row click and displays the chart instead of the navigating through the link. I have referenced a stack article on this topic but it may not be working correctly for me.

[Stop table row toggle upon clicking link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20699358/stop-table-row-toggle-upon-clicking-link)

What the answer given & accepted was:

```
$('a').click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

I tried inserting my script:

```
$('a').click(function(drawGoogleChart){
    drawGoogleChart.stopPropagation();
});
```

But it still was not working for me

PHP For creating table dynamically with a SQL query as the data point

```
echo "<table id='test_table' class='table table-hover tablesorter'>";
    echo "<thead>";
        echo "<tr>";
            echo "<th>TestColA</th><th>TestColC</th><th>TestColC</th>";
        echo "</tr>";
    echo "</thead>";
    echo "<tbody>";
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($db_query){
            $valA = $row[0]; #first element is an id for toggle
            echo "<tr onclick='drawGoogleChart(\"$valA\")';>";
                echo "<td>$row[0]</td>";
                echo "<td><a href="www.google.com" target='_blank'>$row[1]</a></td>";
                echo "<td>$row[2]</td>";
           echo "</tr>";

           // Child Row
           echo "<tr class='tablesorter-childRow'>";
           echo "<td><div id=\"$chart_holder\"></div></td>";
           echo "</tr>";
        }
    echo "</tbody>";
echo "</table>";
```

CSS For row toggle

```
.tablesorter-childRow {
    display: none;
}
.tablesorter-childRow.show {
    display: table-row !important;
}
```

JS For row toggle

```
$(function() {

    var $table = $('.tablesorter');

    $table.tablesorter({
        widgets: ['stickyHeaders', 'filter'],
        widgetOptions: {
            stickyHeaders_offset : 50,
            filter_placeholder : {search : ''},
            filter_saveFilters: true,
            pager_output: '{startRow} - {endRow} / {filteredRows} ({totalRows})',
            pager_removeRows: false,
            filter_childRows  : true,
            filter_cssFilter  : 'tablesorter-filter',
            filter_startsWith : false,
            filter_ignoreCase : true
        }
        });
    // Clear buttons
    add_clear_buttons();

    // make toggles clickable
    $table.on('click', '.tablesorter-hasChildRow', function() {
        $(this)
            .closest('tr')
            .nextUntil('tr:not(.tablesorter-childRow)')
            .toggleClass('show');
        return false;
    });

});
```

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sdsobvp9/43/

Comment: Could you provide a working [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net) showing your problem?

Comment: @JiFus JS Fiddle has been added to the bottom

Comment: A simple hacky solutions is using `$(e.target).click();` in your handling code, but I'll see if I can come up with a cleaner solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you need to stop the propagation of the event when the link is clicked.

A way to do this is by adding this code:

```
// Stop propagation click event to the table if an anchor is clicked
$('.tablesorter').on('click', 'a', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation()
})
```

Adding it to your JSFiddle, it would become this: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sdsobvp9/59/)

Comment: Fantastic, thanks. What I tried did not have the ('.tablesorter'). which caused mine to not work. Thanks for the missing piece

Comment: The difference between `$('.tablesorter').on('click', 'a', function(e) {}` and `$('a').on('click', function(e) {}` is that the last one won't bind any click listeners to anchors added after the first time the click listener is bound. If you use the first version, it adds the click listener on the table, which then in turn will look for the anchor. That way you can generate anchors within the table on the fly.